# Page not displaying in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have a page that refuses to render in IE6.  When I load the page I get a popup message saying 'This page contains both secure and nonsecure items.  Do you want to display the nonsecure items?'  No matter what I click I get HTTP 404 response.

However, when I go uncheck the option 'Show friendly HTTP error messages', the page displays fine.  What could be the cause?

I ran my page through the W3C Markup validation service, but none of the issues seem to be responsible.  I fixed most of the errors, but I have a similar page that displays fine in IE6, so I think there might be a different cause.

The only issues I'm still getting in the W3C Markup validation service are all related to using attributes not allowed by the elements, such as autocomplete=off.

My doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

That's transitional, not strict... Which is why I ignored it.  Or do I not understand 'transitional' correctly?

Comment: Do you have the page loading resources from both http and https? Can you put all of those resources on the same system (http or https) as the page?

Comment: +1 for the name, even if it is really yours. Great bass player.

Comment: All the resources are loading from https.  Only references to http is in the doctype, xmlns and 1 link.

Comment: Fair enough, I updated to indicate the errors I'm getting.  However, I have a VERY similar page which isn't giving me any issues.  That's what I don't get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out the problem was with the CSS referencing images which don't exist.  I discovered this by loading the deployed page in Fiddler.